# Construction of multi-bar graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

How to construct a graph like on the attached link

[image]

I have no idea how to put and move the bars in ggplot2

Thank you in advance for your help

For ease of data transfer

```
data <- data.frame(klm=c(1L,2L,3L),
            year=c(rep(2000,3),rep(2016,3)),
            Category1=c(c(1313,1057,981),c(1456,1200,1124)),
            Category2=c(c(1661,1057,981),c(1827,1444,1400)))


data$klm <- factor(data$klm, levels=1:3, labels=c("Belgium", "Netherlands","Germany"))

data$rok <- factor(data$year,levels=c(2000,2016))




 ggplot(data, aes(x = klm)) 
 + geom_bar(aes(y = Category1[1:3])) 
 + geom_bar(aes(y = Category1[4:6]),position = "dodge") 
 + geom_bar(aes(y = Category2[1:3])) 
 + geom_bar(aes(y = Category2[4:6]),position = "dodge")
```

I'm starting, I do not know ggplot well

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why did it not work

Comment: You might be looking for `position = "dodge"`. You wont' be able to  make that legend without fancy tricks.

Comment: ggplot(data, aes(x = klm)) +
       geom_bar(aes(y = Category1[1:3])) +
       geom_bar(aes(y = Category1[4:6]),position = "dodge") +
       geom_bar(aes(y = Category2[1:3])) +
       geom_bar(aes(y = Category2[4:6]),position = "dodge")

Comment: I'm starting, I do not know ggplot well

Comment: Please include code in your question, not in the comments. You can use the [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45076475/edit). Thanks!

Comment: I edited the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will help someone improve it visually

```
data <- data.frame(klm=c(1L,2L,3L),
               year=c(rep(2000,3),rep(2016,3)),
               Category1=c(c(1313,1057,981),c(1456,1200,1124)),
               Category2=c(c(1661,1257,1301),c(1827,1444,1600)))


data$klm <- factor(data$klm, levels=1:3, labels=c("Belgium", "Netherlands","Germany"))

data$year <- factor(data$year,levels=c(2000,2016))

Średnia=
  ggplot(data=data, aes(x=klm, y=Category2, fill=year)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(),colour="black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))+
  geom_text(aes(y = Category2,label = format(Category2,big.mark = " ")),position = position_dodge(width = 1),vjust = -0.5, hjust = 0.5, cex = 3)


Średnia+
  geom_bar(data=data, aes(x=klm, y=Category1, fill=year),stat="identity", width = 0.5,position=position_dodge(), colour="black")+
  geom_text(aes(y = Category1,label = format(Category1,big.mark = " ")),position = position_dodge(width = 1),vjust = -0.5, hjust = 0.5, cex = 3)
```

I do not know how to change the colors of the second bars and how to make the right legend

Thank you for the tips